# Why is URL doubled up

Tags: php, html, image

I have images in a folder called "img" in a database and the link is

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="img/<?php echo $myrow['img'];?>"/>
```

but the images don't display.
When I check in devtools in Chrome the src says img/img/picname.
There is an img/ too much!
When I remove the first img/ in devtools, the image diplays.
When I remove the img/ from the code the image displays.

This is a first so what is happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What does $myrow["img"] contain? DO you have a base href on the page?

Comment: You have inserted img data with `img/picname` that's why its happening.Insert `<img class="thumbnail" src="<?php echo $myrow['img'];?>"/>` this way or insert your img data with `picname`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your database table it must be storing the full path from your root directory.If that is the case then following code should work

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="<?php echo $myrow['img'];?>"/>
```

Comment: I accidentally typed the path in the database too